# Nutch Crawl2.0 error - java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I try to crawl some urls with nutch 2.0, but failed as belows:

org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler urls -dir crawls -depth 5 -topN 100
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
    at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraMapReduceUtils.getSplits(GoraMapReduceUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.gora.store.impl.FileBackedDataStoreBase.getPartitions(FileBackedDataStoreBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraInputFormat.getSplits(GoraInputFormat.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:43)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:180)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:152)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)

can anyone help me? thanks a lot!